# How to keep browser from timing out (long PHP script)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, browser, timeout

The PHP script takes 25 seconds to complete (for 1 person) and probably longer with high traffic. I don't want the *browser* to time out (PHP won't - I `set_time_limit(0);`).

Can someone provide *sample code* on how to make sure the browser doesn't time out (or else explain in detail what to do)? What's the best method? Ajax?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Brian Graham says, "Once javascript starts an ajax request, it runs until it finishes, quits or errors. As far as I know, it should even do this if the user leaves the page."

So, could I simply call the long PHP script via Ajax, and then it would run for however long is needed without ever timing out (even if nothing was returned by the script)?

Comment: ^ agreed. You'll find people much more helpful on stack when they see that you actually accept and give them reputation when they take their time to help you with your problems ;)

Comment: What you need is profiling, so you can find out which parts of your page take long to complete. You can then speed up those parts.

Comment: Here's the thing - about 3/4 of the time involved is contacting a remote server. The speed of this server never changes no matter how much traffic my site has. Do you think the browser would ever have a chance of timing out with high traffic, even if I directly ran the script via the URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That really depends on what your script is doing and what it's sending back, but if you can use AJAX that would be the way to go. Not only would it let you run the request for a long period of time, but wouldn't tie up the browser leaving the user free to continue using the current page until the request is done.

The best way to implement something like this that I've found is to set ignore_user_abort and turn off the time limit. This way you can let the script run in the background. This way the script can continue to run while the user browses your site. They don't even have to stay on the same page. So you fire off the request with AJAX to start it up. Have a loop in that script that updates the progress to the user's session.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); //don't spam the user with cookies for each session_start()
while( ... ) {
    session_start();
    //update status to the user's session
    session_write_close();
    //sleep or whatever
}
```

Obviously this doesn't have to be a loop. You can simply close the session before you start processing information, then open it, set a status, and close it again. Only one script can access a user's session at a time, so you need to make sure this process isn't tying that up.

Then all you need to do is make a script that runs on the pages of your site that lets the user know when whatever it is you're doing is done and/or provides them the file/output/etc.

This frees up the user to continue browsing your site while your script is running and doesn't force them to sit on a single page staring at a loading indicator.

Comment: This is looking like the best solution to me. Start the process via Ajax, then use Ajax to check a session's value, and once the process has finished, display the result. This should stop a browser from timing out because the process will still run even if aborted by the browser.

Comment: That's correct :) as long as you don't need to directly return any results from that script to the browser, this works. If you need to write any output to the browser, you'll need to write your own communication channel that uses a Comet-like polling system to retrieve updates from the session. Best of luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to initiate the main process with an AJAX request and then continually poll the server to check the progress.  There's no way to tell a browser to not time out.  (And understandably so.  If my browser hung for 5 minutes I would be quite confused.)

I suggest assigning each run of the script a unique id, and then passing that back in the AJAX request.  Then, in future status polls, just pass that ID, and the polling script can return the status.  How you handle the status stuff will depend on what exactly is going on.

Comment: I don't really understand how to do the status stuff. Would this easy solution work just as well? - start the process via Ajax, and then every few seconds use Ajax to request a pixel gif from the server (anything to keep the connection alive). Would this keep the script connected? (I'll use onreadystatechange to know when the process has completed).

Comment: Once javascript starts an ajax request, it runs until it finishes, quits or errors. As far as I know, it should even do this if the user leaves the page.

Comment: The kept alive connection would hang on the large request.  Persistent connections finish a request before moving to the next one.  The easiest (though perhaps not best) way to do the process thing (though you should consider some of Jonathon Hibbard's suggestions to try to figure out why the script takes so long), is to create a file named whatever the status id is at the beginning of the script and then delete the file at the end of the script.  Your status checking would then just be: if the file exists, still running, otherwise, finished.

Comment: @BrianGraham could I start the long script via Ajax, and it would finish no matter how long it took (even minutes)? For every browser?

Comment: I am unsure if closing the browser will kill a running php process, but as long as the ajax is compatible with all browsers, there shouldn't be any problem. If anything, use the php `system` or `passthru` commands to kick it into php's background, not requiring the user to be present at all (guaranteed).

Comment: Closing the browser will not always kill the script, though sometimes it will, depending on how Apache handles the request being severed.  Running it in the background is definitely the best option, and I assumed that that was implied in my answer.  Also, don't forget that AJAX requests have a timeout too.  The browser might kill the request before the server does.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the browser to timeout, then here are the only solutions I can possibly think for for you....  Just know this: I set php to time out after 10 seconds.  If it takes longer than that to process - ever - then the script is not something that is suitable for users visiting my site.

1) Optimize your code - Find out what part of your code is taking too long, and determine what you can do to make it faster.

2) Use a push/pull solution.  Push a request to the server and tell it to execute an application.  The application is thrown into a queue to be run, and the server returns the process ID.  A daemon on the server checks the queue and executes the script from *cli* rather than the browser.

3) create separate routines that require separate ajax-style method calls.  Call routine 1 to start a piece of the script.  Call routine 2 to make another ajax request and start the second *after* the first has returned it is finished.  etc.

4) honestly - i'd just find another solution.  obviously if your script is taking that long to execute, something is *terribly* wrong...

Comment: Most of the time (probably about 3/4) is contacting a remote server - the speed of which I cannot control.

Comment: Again, this is something you'll want to separate out.  Creating a queue that is processed by a daemon/cron script or whatever you want to do is how you "take" control of it.

At the end of the day, you have to ask yourself this question:  Are users going to wait until I get a response, or are they going to leave my page before I can even given them a response.

Comment: Hopefully they do wait - the script is actually used to process an order! That's why I'm making sure the browser doesn't time out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have 2 issues::
If they "do" wait, and the browser times out or the server times out, both you __and__ them are screwed..

If they "don't" wait, they may or may not be screwed, but you stand an even higher risk as users don't waste time on slow ass sites.

If they're going to wait, then notifying them that it should be ready in "5 minutes" at least tells them "hey, my stuff takes a while.  Come back later and check the status, or ill email you when its done".

Slow sites = low traffic = you lose (and possibly lose money).

just saying =)